# Migrate from parse to backendless

Tags: parse-platform, backendless

i want to install backendless with terminal in my ubuntu 14.04 server at home and i don't have a clue.
Also after migrating from parse to backendless, do i need to change my parse client sdk ?
Thank you.

Comment: Try using Backendless Standalone installer from Bitnami. You can read instructions [here](https://backendless.com/products/standalone-backendless-quick-start-guide/) and download installer [here](https://backendless.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have a few misconceptions. Backendless is a MBAAS much like Parse, but it is not an IAAS as much as Heroku & MongoDBLabs would be together. As stated with [Parse Server migration steps](https://parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating), Heroku hosts the parse-server source via NODEJS, and then points to MongoDB instance via Config vars.

However, you can [migrate your parse BAAS](https://backendless.com/parse-to-backendless-migration-guide/) to back endless utilizing export/import of tables and objects.

If you are migrating to backendless, you will also need to conform to their API/SDK. That means rewriting your code to work with them.

If you wish to continue using Parse API/SDK, you will need to create a server running NODEJS with Express to run parse-server, and link to an mongoDB instance via Heroku Config vars to the connection using a driver via the standard MongoDB URI.

However, parse-server is limited in scope at this point. It may be some time before everything is sorted out. This is why parse suggest setting up a local instance to develop on, then migrating it to a hosted version before jumping all in. Things like login authentication have some issues and may required some API updates, and email notification don't seemed to work without mail gun or something else added. I'm sure the list will sort out, but it doesn't do much other than point to another mongoDB at this point, which by the way, works very well with MongoDBLabs while continuing to use parse.com.

If you are serious about setting up your own IAAS, I would suggest AWS before worrying with parse. AWS has its own SDK across multiple platforms and is leading in terms of IAAS. Microsoft has Azure, which is another leader. Then there is Google. The list goes on, but I think you are getting the idea by this point.

I hope this helps. I know it has completely killed my development that was less than 30 days from seeing real world results in my employer's enterprise. Fortunately, they are very understanding and are willing to wait while I get another backend going.

Comment: Please don't waste energy on silly unfocused questions like this.

Comment: Thank you for your time and words John.

Comment: By the way, it is possible to install Backendless Standalone on our computer: https://backendless.com/products/standalone-backendless-quick-start-guide/